# Leaflet clean checkbox in control layers

Tags: leaflet, javascript, web-mapping, html, web

I want to remove a layer from the map and uncheck its control layer checkbox. According to the code bellow the layer is removed from the map, however its checkbox remain checked in control layers. Any hint on how I can clean or uncheck the layer checkbox after removing it from the map?

```
map.on('layeradd', function (event) {
    if (event.layer == layer1) {
        $('#layer1')[0].textContent = 'MyLayer'
        $('#legend-layer1')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: show')

        if (map.hasLayer(layer2)) {
            map.removeLayer(layer2)
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Leaflet is not entirely happy with layer removal inside layer event. You can remedy this by putting layer removal in `setTimeout` event processing function with slight delay:

```
map.on('layeradd', function (event) {
  if (event.layer == layer1) {
    $('#layer1')[0].textContent = 'MyLayer'
    $('#legend-layer1')[0].setAttribute('style', 'visibility: show')
    if (map.hasLayer(layer2)) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        map.removeLayer(layer2);
      }, 5);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That was it. Leaflet now is happy and removing the layer inside event.

Comment: If answer helped you solve your problem, you can also accept it (not only upvote it), so that it will be clear to others that problem was resolved.